# How to implement points from several classes in the "Calculation"- page in Android?

Tags: android

I have made a project which includes several classes(one of them shown below) where a user chooses one of the alternatives from list, and those alternatives have different points. I need to count how many points user achieved in the "Calculation"-page. How can I do it ? Any tips would be really appreciated :// Thanks...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MultipleChoice extends Activity{
private List<Alternatives> alternatives= new ArrayList<Alternatives>();
ListView list2;
int count = 0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alternatives_listview);


    alternativesList();
    alternativesListView();
    registerClickCallBack();
}

private void registerClickCallBack() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        list2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                switch(position){
                  case 0:
                      count +=0;
                  otherActivity("result");
                  break;

                  case 1:
                      count +=1;
                      otherActivity("result");
                      break;

                  case 2:
                      count +=2;
                      otherActivity("result");
                      break;

                  case 3:
                      count +=3;
                      otherActivity("result");
                      break;

                  case 4:
                      count +=4;
                      otherActivity("result");
                      break;

                } 
            }

            });


            }

private void alternativesListView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayAdapter<Alternatives> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    list2.setAdapter(adapter);
}


private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Alternatives>{
    public MyListAdapter(){
        super(MultipleChoice.this,R.layout.activity_alternatives_listview, alternatives);
    }

    public View  getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View itemView = convertView;
        if(itemView == null){
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_alternatives_listview, parent, false);
    }


        Alternatives svar = alternatives.get(position);

        //Teksten
        TextView tekst = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.aldri);
        tekst.setText(svar.getTekst());

        return itemView;
    }
}


private void alternativesList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Alternatives.add(new Alternatives("Never"));
    Alternatives.add(new Alternatives("Once"));
    Alternatives.add(new Alternatives("One time in month"));
    Alternatives.add(new Alternatives("More than two or three times a week"));
    Alternatives.add(new Alternatives("Almost everyday"));

}

private void otherActivity(String a){
    Intent i=new Intent();
       if (a.equals("result")){
        i.setClass(getApplicationContext(),Result.class);
    }
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps use shared preferences to store an accumulated integer by updating the stored value depending on what the user selects.

Have a look at the doc here...

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Hope this helps.